# Using several NServicebus endpoints

Tags: c#, messaging, nservicebus

I am trying to host 2 endpoints of NServicebus, pointing to 2 different queues and to send the messages to these 2 queues.
For some strange reason it does not work.
I googled and in some places people say that it's possible, in the other places: not possible.

Here's my code which is fine with the single endpoint:

```
//Here I configure the endpoint
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(endpointName: Queue1);

endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();

endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();

_endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).ConfigureAwait(false);
//Here I send a command
_endpointInstance.Send(Queue1, command);
```

But the app crushes if I copy-paste this code using another variable for the new endpoint, for example _endpointInstance2 (means: I use the same code to instantiate a new endpoint)

Comment: Please post the full code of what you're attempting to do.

Comment: You should probably also be awaiting the send.. :)

Answer (score 1):

In v4 and prior you could not host more than one endpoint in an AppDomain. This was rectified in v5 and after. [This sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/multi-hosting/) on the documentation website shows exactly what you're looking for.

Just two things to consider: Make sure you're using the right version (you seem to be using v6 which is fine) and don't reuse the configuration object.